# Using std::placeholders in variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am having difficulty using `std::placeholders` in my function that takes a variadic template. I am starting to think I don't need to use a variadic template, but I've been trying this for so long I'm thinking in the weeds and need someone with a fresh look.

The following templated function takes a regular templated argument and then a variadic argument. It is causing a compiler error:

```
registerEvent<UpdaterComponent, std::_Ph<1>>(EVT_INIT, &UpdaterComponent::initialise, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Compiler error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'Status Component::registerEvent>(const int &,Status UpdaterComponent::* (__cdecl *)(const EventArgs &),std::_Ph<1>)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'Status (__thiscall UpdaterComponent::* )(const EventArgs &)' to 'Status UpdaterComponent::* (__cdecl *)(const EventArgs &)'

What exactly is going wrong here and how I can fix this compiler error?

```
// In class Component
template<typename T, typename... Params>
Status registerEvent(int evtId, Status T::*func(const EventArgs& evtArgs), Params...)
{
    ... irrelevant code removed for brevity

    auto res = std::bind(func, this, Params...);

    ... irrelevant code removed for brevity
}


// Usage
class UpdaterComponent : public Component
{
public:
    UpdaterComponent()
    {
        registerEvent<UpdaterComponent, std::_Ph<1>>(EVT_INIT, &UpdaterComponent::initialise, std::placeholders::_1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show `UpdaterComponent::initialise` ?

Comment: Also, `Status T::*func(const EventArgs& evtArgs)` should probably be `Status (T::*func)(const EventArgs& evtArgs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're missing parentheses:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params>
Status registerEvent(int evtId, Status (T::*func)(const EventArgs& evtArgs), Params...)
                                      ^^^       ^^^
```

So you end up getting the type of `func` wrong.

Once you fix that, why are you explicitly providing all the template parameters? That's what template deduction is for! And when you find yourself typing `std::_Ph`, don't. This suffices:

```
registerEvent(EVT_INIT, &UpdaterComponent::initialise, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Why am I explicitly providing all the template parameters? I'm unsure where in the code you are referring to. Are you referring to the implementation of `Component::registerEvent()` parameters or the usage of that function template parameters?

Comment: @JakeM You are explicitly calling `registerEvent<UpdaterComponent, std::_Ph<1>>`. You don't need to do that. You can just call `registerEvent`.